# Achieving "same" colour of different transparencies

Tags: css, colors

Consider 2 or more boxes that look to be the "same" colour, but with different transparencies:

[image]

In this example, the left div is `rgba(200,200,200,0.8)`, and the right `rgba(150,150,150,0.4)`. The second row has a red bar behind them to show that their transparencies are different.
I know the left and right divs do *not* look the same (the left div looks *slightly* darker). My question is how can I make them so:

Given a colour `(r1, g1, b1, a1)`, how can I work out another "colour" `(r2, g2, b2, a2)` such that `a1 != a2` and the two colours look the "same".

Here's the fiddle I used to generate the above picture: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moqpt1t4/)

At the moment, I simply pick some `r2`, `g2`, and `b2`, then fiddle around with `a2` until the two colours look similar enough. But there should be a relation between colours and their transparencies that we can use to work this out precisely and for any given colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link : https://viget.com/inspire/equating-color-and-transparency.

I hope it will be what you're looking for.

**Edit:**
Here is an example of application of the formula given in the link above, based on the case you describe in your post, so you can better understand how to use it.

Here is the formula given in the link. I just changed the name of the variables to make them more explicit ("overlay" became "initialValue", "target" became "finalValue"):

```
finalValue = opacity x initialValue + (1 - opacity) x background
```

From this, I can deduce the following formula :

```
opacity = (background - finalValue) / (background - initialValue)
```

So, back to your example case, the first formula applied to your left div gives a finalValue of :

```
finalValue = 0.8 x 200 + 0.2 x 255 = 211
```

So, the objective for your right div is to calculate the opacity necessary to match this final value, from the initial value of 150 :

```
opacity = (255 - 211) / (255 - 150) = 0.419
```

If you try `rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.419)` on your right div, you will see that the final color is the same.

Comment: Excellent, I was working through the website when you updated the answer. Here's the 0.419 opacity as you worked out: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moqpt1t4/1/) :) The difference in terminology here and the website is a little confusing.

Comment: Assumed that to generalise this for any colour, I can just apply the same formula component-wise, but I found it easiest to fix the opacity this time and derive the new rgb: [different opacities of the same blue](https://jsfiddle.net/moqpt1t4/2/). One problem I have is that I tried fixing opacity to 0.4 at first, but the new red component works out to be negative.

Comment: So you first fix both left and right opacity, then the left rgb for example and finally you calculate the right rgb ?

Comment: Yes. I will have to sit down and rename the var and rearrange the formulas so I get it the way I want. We should be able to say what are the range of possible opacities as well, I think.

Comment: You can simply create a spreadcheet which calculate a set rgb colors corresponding to a round opacity (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc.) from a given final output color you want.